# memory increasing switching between tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Helo all,

I have two table views A & B.on a i have a plain table view but on B table view i have a custom table view. When i click on item of table view i redirected to table view B. So i am switching between from table view A to table view B multiple times.By doing this process memory is keep on increasing.

example.[image]

Memory increase:
[image]

memory is keep on increasing.Even if  i don't write code under **cellForRowAtIndexPath** the memory is always keep on increasing.Please help me out of this.

Comment: For switching you mean that those TableView are each one on a different View Controller? Anyway, when your memory increase is because of a strong reference that is not released when it should. Check if the content of some cell ( any image for example ) is still kept in ref from some other external object ( eg. First View controller keep reference to an object of Second View controller )

Comment: yes they are in diffrent view controllers

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: So u are saying the controller B is Custom table 
View , that means u added that back button there right , if yes are you using segue to go back to A controller and that's not the right way you should like pop the controller from the top .

Comment: Yes exactly.you are right

Comment: @DheerajKumar Well, you can enable the NSZombie ( just for debug, after that disable it, see the docs for the usage ) or use the Instruments tool ( Memory leak option ) for identifying the issue

Comment: i checked with memory leak.I didn't get.

Answer (score 0):

Use allocations in instruments.

[image: instruments]
<sub>(source: [appcelerator.com](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/images/download/attachments/29004941/instruments.png))</sub>

Here you can see "Created & Still living". Or check memory heap. and check each object summary. In place of "Statistics" follow "Call Tree" to narrow down your issue.

This will help you to track the strong reference, also check that you are not **reinitialising** "TableView A" in viewWillAppear. So the Alloc will happen again and again.